# Some conditions which fail when $T$ is not linear.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I came across this question in my self study of a little fuctional analysis and I'd help in solving it. I have also attempted it in the hope that I'll be corrected where I made mistakes. Thanks.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces and $T:X\to Y$ be linear. I want to show the following:
>
> (a) $T$ is continuous if and only if it is continuous at a single point $x_0$ in $X$.
>   (b) $T$ is Lipschitz if and only if it is continuous.
>    (c) Neither (i) nor (ii) hold in the absence of the linearity assumption on $T$.

**Attempts.**

(a)
   $(\Rightarrow)$ Obvious, since if $T$ is continuous everywhere in $X$, then it is certainly continuous at a point $x_0\in X$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that $T$ is continuous at $x_0 \in X$. Let $\varepsilon \gt 0$ be given. Then there is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that $\|T(x)-T(x_0)\|\lt \varepsilon$ whenever $\|x-x_0\|\lt \delta.$ Let $x_1$ be any arbitrary point in $X$.  Then for $\|x-x_1\| = \|(x + x_0 -x_1)-x_0\|\lt \delta$, 
  \begin{align*}
  \|T(x)-T(x_1)\| & = \|T(x)+T(x_0)-T(x_1)-T(x_0)\| \\
  & = \|T(x + x_0 -x_1)-T(x_0)\|\qquad(\because T ~\text{is linear})\\
  & \lt \varepsilon.
  \end{align*}
(b)
$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $T$ is continuous. Then $T$ is bounded. So there exists an $M\geqslant 0$ such that for $x,y\in X$ $$\|T(x)-T(y)\| \leq M \|x-y\|,$$ which is precisely the condition for $T$ to be Lipschitz.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $T$ is Lipschitz. Then $T$ is bounded. Hence $T$ is continuous.

(c) at the moment, I can only think of $T(x) =x^2$ whichs is not linear but continuous everywhere. However, I can't quite deduce which of (a) or (b) fails to hold.

Comment: For (c), you are looking for two things: a nonlinear function which is continuous at (at least) one point, but not continuous; and a nonlinear function which is continuous but not Lipschitz.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the question incorrectly. It did not ask "Show that is T is not linear then either a) or b) fail to hold", but rather "Find an example of T non-linear where a) fails to hold. Do the same for b)." Of course you can think of a function which is continuous at a single point but not everywhere. And you can think of a non-linear function which is continuous, but not Lipschitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a)$ and $(b)$ look right. As for $(c)$:

The function 
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
1 & x \geq 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Is non-linear and continuous at $5$ but not continuous everywhere on $\mathbb R$. So this is a counterexample for $(a)$. For $(b)$, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Examples) gives you $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(x) = x^2$ as an example of a function that's continuous but not Lipschitz continuous.

To see why $f(x) = x^2$ is not Lipschitz continuous note that "$f : X \to Y$ is Lipschitz" means that there exists a constant $K$ such that for all $x \in X$ we have $\frac{|f(x) - f(x^\prime)|}{|x - x^\prime|} < K$. So in particular, $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{|f(x) - f(x + \Delta)|}{\Delta} < K$. For $f(x) = x^2$ you have $f^\prime (x) = 2x$. We are on $\mathbb R$ so this means that for every constant $K$ you can find an $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) > K$ so $f$ cannot be Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. how do I show that $f(x) = x^2$ is not Lipschitz?

Comment: @kuku I added it to my answer. Does this help?

Comment: yes it does. thanks.

Comment: @kuku I'm glad. : )